# Angular if statement with observable async

Tags: angular

I have tried this code bellow and it doesn't work

```
this.users$ = this.userService.get();
```

```
<span *ngIf="!users$ | async">No data</span>
```

Comment: `!(users$ | async)`

Comment: It's working :), TNX

Comment: I've expanded my comment into an answer and explanation, if you care to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of misunderstanding the negation operator, `!` in template syntax.

In the provided code sample, `!users$ | async` examines the `users$` observable for nullness and then applies the `async` pipe, making the observable's emitted value available to the template.

Because that observable is the result of an api call, it can never be null. You want to examine the emitted value from that observable for nullness, so you instead need to wrap the entire expression in parenthesis `!(users$ | async)`.